# Não consigo fazer upload de imagens no Chrome - Play! Framework

Tags: javascript, java, upload, play-framework

Olá,

Estou utilizando o Play! Framework e estou tendo um problema ao tentar fazer upload de imagens, especialmente no Google Chrome:

```
[error] play - Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:433)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:128)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779)
```

No client-side, esse é o código que faz o request para upload das imagens:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.images.length; i++) {
  formData.append('picture' + i, $scope.images[i]);
}

$http.post('/resource/ad/' + id + '/upload', formData, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
});
```

No servidor, está implementado desta forma:

```
play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> files = body.getFiles();
```

Alterei os valores dos meus parâmetros no application.conf para:

```
parsers.MultipartFormData.maxLength=50240K
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=50240K
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=50240K
```

O curioso é que só acontece no Chrome, no Firefox por exemplo, que é o outro navegador que utilizo, as imagens são carregadas normalmente.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e pode me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Obrigado!